# strange data in array.toSource() learning genetic algorithm

Tags: javascript, genetic-algorithm

I'm just starting to learn genetic algorithms and I'm essentially writting this tutorial http://lethain.com/entry/2009/jan/02/genetic-algorithms-cool-name-damn-simple/ to javascript. with a few changes which better represent my dataset.

Anyway, when I output via newPop.toSource(), I get

```
[[#1=[[30,22],#2=[30,85],#3=[30,76]...]]],[#1#,#2#,#3#...#15]]]
```

I've never seen my .toSource output look like this, I was expecting just an array with two arrays inside it

My code is

```
var newPop=populate(data,population,0,70);

function individual(population, min, max){
   var newIndivids=[];
   for(s in population){
      newIndivids.push(population[s]);
     newIndivids[s][0]+=rand;
   }
   return newIndivids;

}

function populate(count,population,min,max){
    var popul=[];
    for(indiv in count){
     popul.push(individual(population,min,max));
    }
    return popul;
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong in my code which is giving me this strange array structure??

Comment: Hmm skynet.js has became self aware?

Comment: Are you sure that code is right?  It has at least one syntax error.

Comment: Yeah as Pointy.. points out, your missing a closing paren after pop.push, also id recommend not using the word pop, since pop is a method for popping off the last item in an array.

Comment: Also, you've forgotten the `var` keyword for declaring "s" and "indiv".

Comment: What browser are you using?  Chrome doesn't even think there is a "toSource" method on Array instances.

Comment: Thanks, I've actually got this running on one machine and copied it over to this one to post, oops, forgot the closing paren. I don't have a var on either "s" or "indiv". I'm not getting any errors though, I thought you didn't need them. I added the "var", and still get the same strange output.

Comment: Using firefox with firebug. no errors shown though.

Comment: OK - well `var` is a really good idea unless you **know** you want a global variable - usually, using a global variable for an array index is kind-of crazy :-)  Are we all sure we understand what exactly is "strange" about the "toSource()" output?

Comment: The 'strange' part was the #1, #2, all that stuff. infinity got the answer, which was to JSON.stringify the response. I've added the var in. Thanks for the tip on that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what those `#1, #2, ...` things are, but `toSource()` is gecko specific: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toSource
My guess is that it's some kind of "reference" to the object in memory at that point, i.e. not portable output.

I suggest you use `JSON.stringify` instead, which will output a portable string representation of your data structure.

The `JSON` global object will be available in Firefox/Safari/Chrome out of the box, but if you also need it in IE you can get it here: http://www.json.org/js.html

Then to reverse this and get back an actual living object, use `JSON.parse`:

```
var data = JSON.parse(str);
```

Comment: Funny, I looked at that exact page on mozzilla, but didn't get to your answer. Strangely, when I do JSON.strigify, I get an array, not an object. But that is what I wanted anyway, so I guess that's good.

Comment: Ooops, maybe not the total answer. JSON.stringify is returning the array as a string (or converting it to a string). I need to be able to run through it as an object or array, as in get newPop[3].

Comment: I assumed you just needed to move the data around somehow. I updated my answer, hope that helps. Otherwise why were you trying to do toSource?

Comment: I thought that is what you were going to say. Seems quite inefficient. I had assumed I was doing something wrong in the way I am constructing the arrays. but maybe this is the correct answer. I can't seem to find anything else.